# How to clone my actual android device to AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Call me lazy but I don't want my phone to be connected all the time with my system while test my app(one reason might be: it creates problem as I change my position and posture on my chair), so yes how can I clone my actual android device to AVD in Android Studio.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I clone my actual android device to AVD

You can't. The best approximation is to create an AVD with similar params to your actual device, eg. RAM, screen dimensions, Android API version,  etc. Of course, keep in mind that it won't simulate your device *exactly* (eg. manufacturers' implementation intricacies etc.).